# Generating an expanding list of lists

Tags: python, recursion

I'm fairly certain this is a recursion problem but I've been going round in circles trying to figure it out.

I would like to generate a matrix (list of lists) over a course of n years to look at all possible outcomes of salary growth.

Salary should be greater than 0 and less than 10000. I want to increment in blocks of 500.

```
salary_range = range(0,10000)
salary_increment = 500
```

So in year 0 salary could be 500,1000,1500.....9500,10000

Then in year 1 for each value of the previous year it can increase by a multiple of 500 so long as it adds to less than 100000. i.e 1000+500*0, 1000+500*1....

It would do this for n years

In the end I would hope to have a list of lists of lists where the sub-list has n items each of which represents the salary at that point in time.

e.g

```
[
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,500]
 [0,0,0,1000]
 .........
 [10000,10000,10000,9500]
 [10000,10000,10000,10000]

]
```

I figured the way to generate the increments would be like

```
def nextone(pv):
    global salary_max
    salary_increment = 500
    next_vals = []

    for i in range(0,n):
        nv = pv+i*salary_increment
        next_vals.append(nv)
```

That spits out a list from a single value but how can I generate this recursively (if that's correct)?

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need recursion. If you wanna generate a matrix just use 2 for loops:

```
all_salary = []
start_salary = [0,0,0,0]
for i in range(3, -1, -1):
    for salary in range(0, 10001, 500):
        start_salary[i] = salary
        print(start_salary)
```

gives us

```
[0, 0, 7500, 10000]
[0, 0, 8000, 10000]
[0, 0, 8500, 10000]
[0, 0, 9000, 10000]
[0, 0, 9500, 10000]
[0, 0, 10000, 10000]
[0, 0, 10000, 10000]
[0, 500, 10000, 10000]
[0, 1000, 10000, 10000]
[0, 1500, 10000, 10000]
[0, 2000, 10000, 10000]
[0, 2500, 10000, 10000]
```

note that we get `[0, 0, 10000, 10000]` twice, one at end of second loop, and one at the beginning of the first.

Then we need to save them to one object, but the code below gives us a list of lists full of 10000 because it appends the same object start_salary, which in the end is [10000, 10000, 10000, 10000] to all_salary:

```
all_salary = []
start_salary = [0,0,0,0]
for i in range(3, -1, -1):
    for salary in range(0, 10001, 500):

        start_salary[i] = salary
        print(start_salary)
        all_salary.append(start_salary)
```

To go round it I simply extend all_salary with start_salary and then chop it the way I need to create list of lists:

```
n = 4
[all_salary[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(all_salary), n)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that interesting to see. I tried a different way to append `all_salary.append(eval(str(start_salary)))` Could you tell me why you set it to work backwards?

Comment: @Charlie what do you mean "set it to work backwards"?